# How to import async Server Components into Client Components in Nextjs 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

I am experimenting with Next.js 13 app directory and React 18's Server Components.
 Following the documentation I put an `async fetch()` call inside a Server Component and I mark the component as async.

But then when I place it as a child of a Client Component, it fails with error

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

If I place it as a child of another Server Component, it works as intended.

Why?

[image]

Code here:

```
### page.tsx
import { ClientComp } from './ClientComp'

export default function Page() {
  return <ClientComp />
}

### ClientComp.tsx
"use client";
import { ServerComp } from "./ServerComp";

export function ClientComp() {
  {/* @ts-expect-error Async Server Component */}
  return <ServerComp />
}

### ServerComp.tsx
export async function ServerComp() {
  return <h2>ServerComp</h2>
}
```

Comment: Post code. It sounds like you're marking your `list.ts` component function with `async`. You can't do that. React components must be computed synchronously.

Comment: You can inside the app directory with Next.js 13. Here some the docs
https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching#asyncawait-in-server-components

Comment: Nextjs official documentation explained how to do it https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns

Answer (score 11):

> ### Importing Server Components into Client Components
>
> Server and Client Components can be interleaved in the same component tree. Behind the scenes, React will merge the work of both environments.
> However, in React, there's a restriction around importing Server Components inside Client Components because Server Components might have server-only code (e.g. database or filesystem utilities).
> For example, importing a Server Component in a Client Component **will not work**

so you cannot do this:

```js
import ServerComponent from './ServerComponent';

export default function ClientComponent() {
  return (
    <>
      <ServerComponent />
    </>
  );
}
```

Instead, you can pass a Server Component as a child or prop of a Client Component. You can do this by wrapping both components in another Server Component. For example:

```js
// ✅ This pattern works. You can pass a Server Component
// as a child or prop of a Client Component.
import ClientComponent from "./ClientComponent";
import ServerComponent from "./ServerComponent";

// Pages are Server Components by default
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ClientComponent>
      <ServerComponent />
    </ClientComponent>
  );
}
```

Comment: Except if I want to pass a piece of state or function created inside the Client component to the Server component, I cannot do it using `{children}` pattern. 

I am creating a client component with `useState()` and I want to pass the value and setter to the child server component. 
So the server component can make an api request using value as param.

Comment: I don't see why you want to do that and better is to use a client component instead but I think it's not even possible

Comment: having the same issue -- @Cla, did you ever figure out a workaround?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out in the end. When you want to trigger a re-rendering of a server component (with its eventual networking call), you cannot do it directly from the client component. 
But if your client component updates the URL, adding or changing a query param for example, the server component will re-render. This way you can achieve the same result. Then of course there are nuances of what you can and cannot do with this strategy

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, I wanted to pass props to the server component, but its impossible to change the state of the server component.

What you can do is to **put all your state in a client component**, then place the server component in server one and wrap it with the client one with the state...

for example:

```js
'use client'

export default function MenuButton({ children }: Props) { /* Client Component with state management */
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Button action={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        <HiOutlineBars3BottomLeft />
      </Button>
      <div
        className={`${styles.desktopMenu} ${
          open ? styles.active : styles.inactive
        }`}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}



export default function Navbar() { /* Server component */
  return (
   <header>
      <MenuButton> /* Client component with all state management */
          <DesktopMenu /> /* Async server component */
      </MenuButton>    
   </header>
         
 );
}
```

Comment: I see what toy are saying. But my specific need was to pass state to the innermost server component as a prop. But I get it’s not really possible. At least yet

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ahmed Sbai's answer,

If you want to pass props from child components to server components, **you can't**.

For example, you might think the following will work as I did:

The following does not work:

```
// # page.tsx
<ClientComponent MyServerComponent={MyServerComponent} />
```

```
// # ClientComponent.tsx
function ClientComponent({ MyServerComponent }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyServerComponent myExampleProp={123} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Full example on [Code Sandbox click here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/server-child-component-examples-23qldr?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx)

---

Instead, you pass the props before serving the component to the client, i.e.: inside the parent server component, you put the props right away:

```
// # page.tsx
<ClientComponent myServerComponent={<MyServerComponent myExampleProp={123} />} />
```

```
// # ClientComponent.tsx
function ClientComponent({ myServerComponent }) {
  return (
    <div>
        {myServerComponent}
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

In summary, when you want to pass data from a child component to a server component, then you're in a wrong situation.

You have to think twice.

You have the following solutions:

**A.** What you really want is to make an AJAX call.

**B.** What you really want is to move that logic to the parent server component (ex: page.tsx).

[image]

Inside **ClientComponent.tsx**:

```
// ClientComponent.tsx
// This is not allowed: ❌

import ServerComponent from './ServerComponent';

export default function ClientComponent() {
  return <ServerComponent />;
}
```

Instead, you do this:

Inside **page.tsx**

```
// page.tsx
// This is allowed  ✅

import ClientComponent from "./ClientComponent";
import ServerComponent from "./ServerComponent";

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ClientComponent>
      <ServerComponent propA={123} />
    </ClientComponent>
  );
}
```

Or you do this:

```
// page.tsx
// This is allowed  ✅

import ClientComponent from "./ClientComponent";
import ServerComponent from "./ServerComponent";

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ClientComponent serverComponent={<ServerComponent propA={123}/>} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you please pass me a link of a working example? I am not able to make this work.

Here my not working setup: https://pastebin.com/aR6niifd

Comment: @Cla. you're correct, I was wrong in my answer, I've updated it now

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Thanks for updating the answer.

Answer (score -3):

To use an async Server Component with TypeScript, ensure you are using TypeScript 5.1.3 or higher and @types/react 18.2.8 or higher.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/typescript#passing-data-between-server--client-components